# How to use 'node-7z' on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, 7zip

I want to use `node-7z` on CentOS. I have tested my app on Mac and it works. When I ran the app on server, it throws an error about

```
Error: spawn 7z ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:450:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:405:17)
```

I think this stated that the app didn't recognize the 7zip correctly but I have already installed 7zip from http://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/p7zip/p7zip/15.09/p7zip_15.09_src_all.tar.bz2 and set the $PATH and alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/data/node/mongodb/bin:/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
alias 7z='7za'
```

I can run `7z i` command so I think it is installed correctly.

The path of 7z is `/usr/local/bin/7za`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this problem by installing `p7zip-plugins`. So if you want to use 7zip on CentOS, you need:

```
sudo yum install p7zip
sudo yum install p7zip-plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT is Error NO ENTry, meaning the file you are trying to work with was not found.

Comment: I saw this error once on my Mac. The reason for that is I forgot to install 7z on Mac. So I suppose this error stated the module can't find 7z command. But I do install 7z on server and I can run '7z a' command which is called by the module.